# How to use ListView to make a TabView in Flutter equal to Telegram?

Tags: flutter

[Telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlVk0.jpg)

I tried to do it using the ListView with Columns and Rows, but there is always some rendering problem, because I can't use the CrossAxisAlignment.stretch to leave the 'Container' white that is under the text with the exact size of the text.

Answer (score 1):

There's a specific widget to create this [TabBar Widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs)

Flutter [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs#interactive-example):

```dart
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can use others packages: [MD2 Tab Indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/md2_tab_indicator)

MD2 Tab Indicator [example:](https://pub.dev/packages/md2_tab_indicator#usage)

```dart
TabBar(
  labelStyle: TextStyle( //up to your taste
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
  ),
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label, //makes it better
  labelColor: Color(0xff1a73e8), //Google's sweet blue
  unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff5f6368), //niceish grey
  isScrollable: true, //up to your taste
  indicator: MD2Indicator( //it begins here
    indicatorHeight: 3,
    indicatorColor: Color(0xff1a73e8),
    indicatorSize: MD2IndicatorSize.normal //3 different modes tiny-normal-full
  ),
  tabs: <Widget>[
    Tab(
      text: "Home",
    ),
    Tab(
      text: "Personal info",
    ),
    Tab(
      text: "Data & personalization",
    ),
    Tab(
      text: "Security",
    )
  ],
),
```

[image: Gif]